# Find duplicates and permutations in large file

Tags: java, arrays, duplicates

I have a problem that i been trying to figure out. What I try to do is find the number of pairs of entries(every line is one entry) that contains the same characters.

My approach was to read every line, sort the line and then compare to the others. The problem is that I do not get every pair of duplicates.

Here is my code:

```
public static int countduplicates(String dbfilename) throws IOException {
    int counter = 0;

    Set<String> checker;
    BufferedReader list = new BufferedReader( new FileReader( dbfilename ) );
    String line;
    TreeMap<String,Integer> map  = new TreeMap<>();

    while ( (line = list.readLine()) != null )
    {
       String newline= sorted(line);

       System.out.println("Sorted: " + newline);

        if (!map.containsKey(newline))
        {
            map.put(newline, 0);
        }
        else {
            counter++;
            map.put(newline, 1);
        }
    }



    list.close();
    return counter;

}
}
```

I get why it is not working, because for example if I have the input file like:

```
BCDEFGH
ABACD
BDCEF
BDCAA
DBACA
DABACA
DABAC
```

Sorted I will get

```
BCDEFGH
AABCD
BCDEF
AABCD
AABCD (*)
AAABCD
AABCD
```

But will only get the output 3 instead of 6 because (*) will only add 1 to counter when it should add 2. Can any of you give me any hint on how to continue with this problem?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it correctly you can simply count the occurences of each sorted entry with a map:

```
(entry) -> n
=============
BCDEFGH -> 1
AABCD   -> 4
BCDEF   -> 1
AAABCD  -> 1
```

Now to find the number of pairs for each entry just use the [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number)

```
numbersOfPairs = (n*n - n) / 2
```

and you are done. This would give you the following numbers

```
(entry) -> numberOfPairs
=============
BCDEFGH -> 0
AABCD   -> 6
BCDEF   -> 0
AAABCD  -> 0
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you right,
first, map does not allow duplicate keys. I see in your code in

```
 else 
 {
 counter++;
 map.put(newline, 1);
 }
```

you are always setting the count of the entry to one regardless how many times it has been there.

For example three times `AABCD` will be 1 in the map.

> "But will only get the output 3 instead of 6 because (*) will only add
>   1 to counter when it should add 2. "

That is because what I mentioned above, map not letting duplicate keys.

```
BCDEFGH
AABCD 
BCDEF 
AABCD
AABCD 
AAABCD 
AABCD
```

going to be

```
BCDEFGH -> 1 times
AABCD   -> 4 times
BCDEF   -> 1 times
AAABCD  -> 1 times
```

You could read more about map [here.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
      newline = newline.substring(0, 
                                newline.indexOf(  "(" ) ).trim();
```

Try adding the above line before the if condition

```
        if (!map.containsKey(newline))
        {
               map.put(newline, 0);
        }
       else {
               counter++;
                map.put(newline, 1);
        }
```